# Eclipse Python Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging

Brand new to python, running it in eclipse. Running the following code

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

I received this error:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'sitecustomize'
Hello, World!
```

Then I tried running this line, found it in a blog site.

```
PYTHONVERBOSE=1 conda update --all
```

and got this error:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'sitecustomize'
  File "\config\workspace\MyTestProject\src1\root\nested\example.py", line 9
    PYTHONVERBOSE=1 conda update --all
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in another post [After installing Anaconda, I get constant "KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321973/after-installing-anaconda-i-get-constant-keyerror-pythonpath-messages)

I changed the name of the file 'sitecustomize' and code ran without error.